# Swift: Why does the iPad/Mac app version look weird

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipados

How can I fix this? It's showing up on my Mac + iPad. On iPhone is looks normal. I don't really know what to add besides an ss, so if you need anything, please ask. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What does "looks weird" mean?  If you are using a master/detail view then this looks normal; iPads can display both views at the same time while an iPhone does not. Running on Mac gives the same view as iPad.  What should it look like?

Comment: Shouldn't it expand to full screen. The app is running in the what looks like "bookmark bar"

Comment: No, it won't run fullscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely referring to the `navigationViewStyle`

The iPad and Mac have a `DefaultNavigationViewStyle` of `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle`/`columns` and the iPhone has a default of `StackNavigationViewStyle`/`stack`.

If you haven't set it it will change with the device. If you add the line below to your code on the upper most `View` it will likely "appear" to be fixed.

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

If you are using SwiftUI.