# when I open the app on ipad simulator the design is broken

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I run the app on the iPad, the design does not appear on the screen. When you click on Home in the top left navigation bar, the design comes up, but it is half loaded. When I delete the NavigationView, the normal design appears but is not clickable.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: BlogPostsStore
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var featuredPosts: [BlogPost] {
        return store.blogPosts.filter {$0.featured == true}
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                // featured article
                if featuredPosts.count > 0 {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Featured posts")
                                .font(.title.bold())
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(featuredPosts) {post in
                                NavigationLink(destination: BlogPostView(blogPost: post)) {
                                    BlogPostCardMain(blogPost: post)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .padding(.vertical, 30)
                }
// latest articles
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Latest posts")
                            .font(.title.bold())
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 15) {
                            if store.blogPosts.count >= 3 {
                                ForEach(store.blogPosts[0...2]) {post in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: BlogPostView(blogPost: post)) {
                                        BlogPostCardMain(blogPost: post)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                ForEach(store.blogPosts[0..<store.blogPosts.count]) {post in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: BlogPostView(blogPost: post)) {
                                        BlogPostCardMain(blogPost: post)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                        .padding(.trailing, 30)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 420)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: {store.refreshView()}) { Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClAU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EABMs.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Why does the iPad/Mac app version look weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482156/swift-why-does-the-ipad-mac-app-version-look-weird)

Comment: This is by design not weird see the link above for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is down to how `NavigationView` works on iPads (and also larger iPhones in landscape).

The first view given to NavigationView acts as the collapsible left hand navigation, which is a fixed width. Any `NavigationLink` destinations in that view will open in the main, “detail” view that takes up the full screen.

You can specify a second view underneath the first one to provide a ‘default’ view to display in the main screen:

```swift
NavigationView {
  // the sidebar view
  ScrollView {
    // etc.
  }
  // the default view
  Text("Default view")
}
```

You could also add a third view, which will automatically give your iPad a three-column view similar to that used by Mail, etc. if you wanted to.

Another option is to force the NavigationView to work exactly the same way as it does for an iPhone in portrait mode, by adding a `.navigationViewStyle` argument:

```swift
NavigationView {
  // contents as before
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

While that will give you an iPhone-like experience on the iPad, it doesn’t really take full use of the larger screen space without careful design work. For that reason, it’s usually a good idea to invest some time in coming up with an app design that is tailored to the default iPad style of navigation view.