# Why does my playground liveView look like an iPad instead of an iPhone in Xcode 15.2?

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

As title.
I have few code want to show in the playground liveView.
I wish it looks like iPhone, but it's not.
How to change the liveView to iPhone simulator in Xcode 15.2.
Should I miss some Xcode setting?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    Text("Test 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    Text("Test 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hello World")
        }
            
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(
    rootView: ContentView()
)
```

[image]

Comment: How does it "look like" an iPad? It doesn't look like an iPad to me, and neither does it look like an iPhone.  What do you expect to see exactly?

Comment: Try changing `NavigationView` to `NavigationStack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationView`’s “default style” for iPad/Mac is a Master/Detail setup vs a Stack setup.

What you are seeing is the Navigation’s 3rd view, it becomes obvious if you add one line to your code.

```
NavigationView {
        
        List{
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                Text("Test 1")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                Text("Test 2")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Hello World")

        Text(“third view”) ///<<——- here
    }
```

You can “solve” it by setting the navigation style.

[Swift: Why does the iPad/Mac app version look weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482156/swift-why-does-the-ipad-mac-app-version-look-weird/70482643#70482643)

Or using the newer and much better`NavigationStack`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: Thank you. NavigationStack is the answer.